# exporting db objects for version control

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, ddl, database-metadata

We are implementing version control for our project. As part of this we need to check in all DB objects. We have tables, procedures, functions, packages, view and materialized view. Problem is there are many objects and we need to put source code file wise. e.g. There are tables T1, T2, T3 and we need files Table_T1.txt which will have T1 definition ( columns definition, indexes for the table and grants) and so on for all objects.

I m aware of metadata tables such as `DBA_VIEWS`, `dba_source` and `DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL` etc where I can find required information **but how to pull that information object wise.** Currently we are working where we are taking entire information for specific object and then segregating (CUT - PASTE) it into the different files. Is there any smart way to tackle this?

Database - Oracle 10g

Comment: I started with preparing script for each object to achieve this. However, one of my office mate found simple way using toad. For other people if you are using toad then there is option when you go to schema -> and select object name and right click (select option as create table). It may very version to version. Hope this helps you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but how to pull that information object wise.

Pass the **parameters** properly. You could then **customize** your output.

```
DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL (object_type, object_name, object_owner)
```

For example, to get the **METADATA** for all the tables in the user **SCOTT**.

```
SQL> conn scott/tiger@pdborcl;
Connected.
SQL> set long 200000
SQL> select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE',t.table_name, 'SCOTT') from US

DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TABLE',T.TABLE_NAME,'SCOTT')
------------------------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE TABLE "SCOTT"."DEPT"
   (    "DEPTNO" NUMBER(2,0),
        "DNAME" VARCHAR2(14),
        "LOC" VARCHAR2(13),
         CONSTRAINT "PK_DEPT" PRIMARY KEY ("DEPTNO")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS"  ENABLE
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS"


  CREATE TABLE "SCOTT"."EMP"
   (    "EMPNO" NUMBER(4,0),
        "ENAME" VARCHAR2(10),
        "JOB" VARCHAR2(9),
        "MGR" NUMBER(4,0),
        "HIREDATE" DATE,
        "SAL" NUMBER(7,2),
        "COMM" NUMBER(7,2),
        "DEPTNO" NUMBER(2,0),
         CONSTRAINT "PK_EMP" PRIMARY KEY ("EMPNO")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS"  ENABLE,
         CONSTRAINT "FK_DEPTNO" FOREIGN KEY ("DEPTNO")
          REFERENCES "SCOTT"."DEPT" ("DEPTNO") ENABLE
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS"


  CREATE TABLE "SCOTT"."BONUS"
   (    "ENAME" VARCHAR2(10),
        "JOB" VARCHAR2(9),
        "SAL" NUMBER,
        "COMM" NUMBER
   ) SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  TABLESPACE "USERS"


  CREATE TABLE "SCOTT"."SALGRADE"
   (    "GRADE" NUMBER,
        "LOSAL" NUMBER,
        "HISAL" NUMBER
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS"
```

So, this gives me the **DDL** for all the tables in the **SCOTT** schema.

Similarly, you could do the same for all other objects like `INDEXES`, `ROLES`  etc.

To get the DDL in a text file, simply use **SPOOL**. So, you just need individual scripts for different object types to spool in respective text files.

Comment: Thanks Lalit. I have tried this earlier also, if you see it will give me one text file for DDL where all info is available. We are cutting info table wise again. Indexes are sitting at different places and so are grants for these tables. In above example SCOTT.BONUS should be present in Table_BONUS.txt file - which should have information about indexes and grants for 'BONUS' table along with DDL. If there are 500 tables in schema then we need 500 differnet text files.

Comment: So what's the problem? Do it in programming. Write your own PL/SQL script to get it done dynamically.

Comment: One possible way to implement a control version at DDL level is to develop our solution based on DBMS_METADATA to extract DDLs and DBMS_METADATA_DIFF (on +11gR1) to extract the differences between two objects.

Comment: I wish OP comes up with his real concern. There is almost nothing impossible.

Answer (score 0):

The simple fact is that you cannot treat the database objects as you treat your Java, C# or other files.

There are many reasons and I'll name a few:

Files are stored locally on the developer’s PC and the change s/he makes do not affect other developers. Likewise, the developer is not affected by changes made by her colleague. In database this is (usually) not the case and developers share the same database environment, so any change that were committed to the database affect others.

Publishing code changes is done using the Check-In / Submit Changes / etc. (depending on which source control tool you use). At that point, the code from the local directory of the developer is inserted into the source control repository. Developer who wants to get the latest code need to request it from the source control tool. In database the change already exists and impacts other data even if it was not checked-in into the repository.

During the file check-in, the source control tool performs a conflict check to see if the same file was modified and checked-in by another developer during the time you modified your local copy. Again there is no check for this in the database. If you alter a procedure from your local PC and at the same time I modify the same procedure with code form my local PC then we override each other’s changes.

The build process of code is done by getting the label / latest version of the code to an empty directory and then perform a build – compile. The output are binaries in which we copy & replace the existing. We don't care what was before. In database we cannot recreate the database as we need to maintain the data! Also the deployment executes SQL scripts which were generated in the build process.

When executing the SQL scripts (with the DDL, DCL, DML (for static content) commands) you assume the current structure of the environment match the structure when you create the scripts. If not, then your scripts can fail as you are trying to add new column which already exists.

Treating SQL scripts as code and manually generating them will cause syntax errors, database dependencies errors, scripts that are not reusable which complicate the task of developing, maintaining, testing those scripts. In addition, those scripts may run on an environment which is different from the one you though it would run on.

Sometimes the script in the version control repository does not match the structure of the object that was tested and then errors will happen in production!

There are many more, but I think you got the picture.

What I found that works is the following:

Use an enforced version control system that enforces check-out/check-in operations on the database objects. This will make sure the version control repository matches the code that was checked-in as it reads the metadata of the object in the check-in operation and not as a separated step done manually

Use an impact analysis that utilize baselines as part of the comparison to identify conflicts and identify if a change (when comparing the object's structure between the source control repository and the database) is a real change that origin from development or a change that was origin from a different path and then it should be skipped, such as different branch or an emergency fix.

An article I wrote on this was published [here](http://www3.dbmaestro.com/the-definitive-guide-to-database-version-control), you are welcome to read it.